# How to call stored procedure in Mssql using loopback 4?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, loopbackjs, loopback, angular-loopback

How to call stored procedure in Mssql using loopback 4 typescript

How do i make query in datasource like calling stored procedure

```
import { DataSourceConstructor} from '@loopback/repository';

export const db = new DataSourceConstructor({
  connector: 'mssql',
  host: '192.168.1.110',
  port: 1433,
  database: 'FastDryNew',
  password: 'sa$123',
  user: 'sa',
});
```

currently i'm using Default Crud Repository with simple where condition

```
  @get('/Job/{CustomerID}')
  @param.path.number('CustomerID')
  async findJobByCustomerID(CustomerID: number): Promise<Jobs[]> {
    return await this.JobsRepo.find({ where: { CustomerID: CustomerID } });
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed datasource config

```
var DataSource = require('loopback-datasource-juggler').DataSource;

export var db = new DataSource({
    connector: require('loopback-connector-mssql'),
    host: '192.168.1.110',
    port: 1433,
    database: 'FastDryNew',
    password: 'sa$123',
    user: 'sa',
});
```

And on Controller imported dataSource

```
import { db } from '../datasources/db.datasource';

@get('/user')
async findUser() {
    let sql = 'select * from [User]';
    db.connector.query(sql, function (err: any, results: User[]) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            return results;
        }
    });
}
```